# Python Django edit record function not working with Jquery Ajax

Tags: python, html, jquery, django, ajax

Context: I have a table in HTML with some data for a specific user. Next to each row there is a delete and an edit button. I want the buttons to do what they are supposed to the certain row. Currently the delete button is working, and I tried a similar approach for the edit button, but when clicked nothing happens.

This is part of the HTML:

```
{% for work_entry in work_entries %}
            {% if work_entry.date == date.date %}
                <form method="POST" id="{{ work_entry.id }}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <tr>
                        {% if work_entry.is_paid == False %}
                            <td> <button class="delete-button" id="{{ work_entry.id }}" style="background-color: #bb1a1a;"
                                         onclick="return confirm('Please confirm you wish to delete the selected record.')">Delete
                                </button>
                            </td>
                            <td> <button class="edit-button" id="{{ work_entry.id }}" style="background-color: #5dbb1a;"
                                         onclick="return confirm('Please confirm you wish to edit the selected record.')">Update
                                </button>
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ work_entry.project }}</td>
                            <td><input style="border: none" class="table-input" type="text" id="description-{{ work_entry.id }}"
                                       value="{{ work_entry.description }}"></td>
                            <td><input type="number" class="table-input" step="0.01" id="hours-{{ work_entry.id }}"
                                       value="{{ work_entry.num_hours }}"></td>
```

This is the js: (Sorry its a little long but should be straight forward)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".delete-button").click(function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id')
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'{% url 'work_entries:object_delete' %}',
        data:{
            id: id,
            action: 'post'
        },
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ csrf_token }}");
        },
        success:function(response){
            $(".main-table").html(response)
        },
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
    }
    });
});
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".edit-button").click(function (e) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id')
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'{% url 'work_entries:object_edit' %}',
            data:{
                id: id,
                description: $('#description-id'),
                hours: $('#hours-id'),
                action: 'post'
            },
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {


    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ csrf_token }}");
        },
        success:function(response){
            $(".main-table").html(response)
        },
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
    }
    });
});
});
```

From what is I see is happening, the edit button does nothing as it is not even getting to the view, nor giving an error. I thought there is an overlap between the delete and edit button, but I didn't find anything on the internet regarding that. Any help, suggestions?

Also note: the rows are meant to have 2 inputs to allow the user to change description and hours. This should be then sent to the view through the edit button where I have a function that updates that record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data

```
description: $('#description-id'),
hours: $('#hours-id'),
```

you don't get the value of your input. Try this

```
description: $('#description-id').val(),
hours: $('#hours-id').val(),
```